# How to know on which column the click event has happened in Antd Table?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, antd, tablecolumn

I have an antd table in which I need to do some operations only when the click event happens on a specific column.

Currently, I am using the onRow prop in the table component as below

```
onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
  return {
    onClick: (event) => {
      // some operations              
    },
  };
}}
```

With this implementation, click is triggered for the entire row ( when clicked on any column )

I have tried to see the column dataIndex or key to return the click event only when the event has happened on a specific column. But args of onRow do not have that data.

Is there a way to achieve the required behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create a table with editable row. I would suggest to create a new column (e.g. Actions) in which you will have a button that when you click it, it will let you edit the row you want. Check the following link, hope it's what you are looking for:

https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-rows-antd-4-20-6-forked-hvul4u?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to capture click events for a specific column, you can use the `onCell` property for [column](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column). ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/colspan-and-rowspan-antd-4-18-5-forked-subol8?file=/index.js))

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    render: (text, row, index) => <a>{text}</a>,
    onCell: (record, rowIndex) => {
      return {
        onClick: () => {
          console.log(record, rowIndex);
        }
      };
    }
  },
...
]
```

Comment: Here I want to set a state ( let's say name ). On Clicking the name column I need to do setName(name_of_the_col_clicked). How to do this?

Comment: You have the record parameter right? `setName(record.name)`.

Comment: `onCell`, `onClick` is for a specific column & you are aware which column it is. `onClick` will only trigger for that specific column.

Comment: Yes, but columns array is outside the component. And I can keep column after the state is defined to get access to setName() I wanted to know if there is a way where columns array stays outside component and be able to do setName() 

Ex: in aggrid we have gridComponents where all column renderers as passed seperately